Is there a way to prove Pappus's Centroid Theorem (volume-related) using the area-related one?
I am curious about proving the Pappus's Centroid Theorem. I have finished proving the area one and I wonder if there is a way to intuitively prove the volume one by using the area one (we can view the area as the integration of different curves, and all of them rotate about one axis and the rotated surfaces integrate to form the solid of revolution).
I prove the first theorem of Pappus's Centroid Theorem by this:
Let $x$-axis be the rotational axis and $y=f(x)$ be the generating curve, the $y$-axis of the centroid of a line segment $f(x)$ can be computed as
$$\bar{y}=\frac{\int y ds}{\int ds}$$
where $s$ is the length.
At the same time the length $ds$ can be computed as
$$ds=\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}dx.$$
So $\bar{y}=\int y \sqrt{1+(dy/dx)^2}dx/s$ and the distance traveled by the centroid of the curve is $2\pi \int y \sqrt{1+(dy/dx)^2}dx/s$.
At the same time, the surface area of a solid of revolution is
$$S=\int 2\pi y \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}dx.$$
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
\text{surface area}&= \displaystyle\int 2xy \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}dx\\
&=s\cdot 2\pi \cdot \int\frac{y \sqrt{1+(dy/dx)^2}dx}{s}\\
&=\text{arc length} \cdot \text{distance traveled by centroid}
\end{align*}
